# What is asyncDispatch() alternative in REST-assured library

Tags: mocking, spring-test, rest-assured, spring-boot-test, spring-test-mvc

I want to use the REST-assured for testing my REST API instead of Spring's MockMvc.

**The idea is that I want to get the status code from the response of the async call using REST-assured library.**

Check below for details:

I use these dependencies:

```
'io.rest-assured:rest-assured:3.0.5'
'io.rest-assured:spring-mock-mvc:3.0.5'
```

When I do:

```
mockMvc.perform(asyncDispatch(result)).andExpect(status().isAccepted());
```

I'm being able to get this status code below (output of `.andDo(print())`) but I want to achieve the same result using REST-assured:

```
Async:
    Async started = true
     Async result = <202 Accepted,{}>
```

With REST-assured I'm only being able to get this status code below:

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = {}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

I tried this way:

```
given()
      .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
      .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
      .body(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(myDto))

      .when()
      .put(URL)

      .then()
      .apply(print())
      .expect(request().asyncStarted())
      .expect(request().asyncResult(notNullValue()))
      .expect(status().isAccepted());
```

Test fails:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :202
Actual   :200
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you're using RestAssured MockMvc you can use `async`:

```
given()
      ...    
      .when()
      .async().put(URL)

      .then()
      ...
```

See documentation [here](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#asynchronous-requests).